# How can I pass in a CSRF token with my API requests if I don't have a user login for my Django site?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

Using the Django rest framework, I have an API endpoint I created that I call within my static files that I would like to pass a CSRF token into so that I'm the only one who can access the API.

My Django site does *not* have users with logins.

I essentially want to do something like this in my API endpoint:

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
def payment(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if (("Authorization" not in requests.headers) or (request.headers["Authorization"] != "token")):
        return Response({"Error": "Not authorized for access."})
    # ...
```

Do I need to generate a token one time and use that repeatedly?

Or can I generate one every time the script is used?

And how can I access this csrf token in my HTML file?

I'm using class-based views and I assume I would pass it in to `get_context_data`, but how would I set up the API endpoint to accept this CSRF token?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `TokenAuthentication` right from the django-restframework:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

You would then pass the token in the header of all your requests
like `Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b`

If you use the decorators from the django-restframework, you can skipp all the custom token validation, as this is done by the django-restframework.

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def payment(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
```

Comment: I mostly follow, but am still confused on how to actually create the token given that I don't have "Users" or have people "log in". How would I create this token?

Comment: You would at least need one user, maybe just your superuser account. Or create a dedicated user for your API calls. There is no login needed, as you are using the token instead. But the token is related to a user instance.

Comment: So would I create the token in the terminal, pass the value I get into the view, then pass it into my HTML file and to the javascript file where I make the API call? Remember I need to use the token in my static JS file to make a call to my API endpoint.

Comment: Where you add the token is completly up to you. You have to make sure nobody has access to your static JS or the HTML you are using the JS, as otherwise they will get the token as well. To do so, you would need some kind of authentification anyhow.

Comment: Is there a way to restrict access to a static JS file in Django? I created my API endpoint in the first place to move code to the backend but it seems there's no way to restrict who can access the endpoint. So is there a way to make the JS static file hidden?